# Error con permisos de localizacion en API 24-26 Android. Se "Minimiza" pero no "truena"

Tags: java, android, permisos

Buen dia a todos.
En las ultimas semanas he estado desarrollando una aplicacion, la cual hace uso de Google maps y Google PlaceAutocompleteFragment.

La estructura basica de la aplicacion es la siguiente:

**Pantalla Splash > Intro Slider de la app > Login > Main Activity**

Les explico el funcionamiento basico de esta estructura. Siempre se mostrara el Splash al inicio de la aplicacion como animacion, despues SOLO se mostrara la primera vez de ejecucion el Intro slider, este llamara traer el Main Activity. En el Main activity se comprobara que exista una secion activa de algun usuario, para poder quedarse ahi. De no ser asi, se manda llamar al Login para que inicie sesion.

Todo funcionaba segun lo esperado, pero todo cambio cuando por error ejecute la aplicacion en un emulador con API distinta en la cual estaba programando (API 22 de Android).

Descubri que en las APIS 24,25,26 de Android la aplicacion truena despues de pasar  **Intro Slider de la app**. El error es:

```
MainActivity has leaked window DecorView@556f35e[] that was originally added here
```

Despues de investigar un poco descubri que este error es por llamar un Dialog despues de haber salido de un Activity. Y si, yo tenia un Dialog que se mostraba en el OnCrete de mi MainActivity. Ok, lo comente, se supone que con eso se arreglaria el error, no?

Pues si, si lo hizo. La aplicacion ya no tronaba, pero ahora lo que pasaba es que en las versiones comentadas la aplicacion se "Minimizaba" traz pasar por el **Intro Slider**. No tronaba. 
Entonces al abrir la aplicacion esta se encontraba en el **Login**.
En el LogCat no me muestra ningun "error" (en color rojo), solo lo siguiente:

> Failed to capture screenshot of Token{00000 ActivityRecord{9ee35cd u0 com...../.MainActivity t10 f}} appWin=Window{74989fb u0 com...../com.......MainActivity} drawState=1
>   05-24 02:19:29.751 4988-4988/com.google.android.packageinstaller I/GrantPermissionsActivity: No package: null
>                                                                                                android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:147)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:132)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.getCallingPackageInfo(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:350)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.onCreate(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:101)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Como lo puedo solucionar? Trate de explicarlo lo mejor posible, muchas gracias de antemano.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Ya se por que pasa esto. Se sigue teniendo el mismo problema que antes, es decir, mando llama un "Dialog" (Si es que asi se le puede llamar). Solo que este Dialog es el de solicitar permiso al usuario para otorgar su ubicacion. Como lo supe? Simple, entre con una cuenta, despues automaticamente me salto el dialogo para dejar a la aplicacion utilizar mi ubicacion. Una vez que acepto, me salgo de la cuenta y cierro la aplicacion y la habro de nuevo, esta vez ya no se minimiza (Antes si).

Entonces la pregunta ahora es... Que puedo hacer? Como mando llamar ese cuadro de dialogo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como mencione en mi actualizacion el error ocurre por que se esta llamando el Dialog de permisos de localizacion inmediatamente despues de cerrar la activity de Intro slider. Para solucionarlo simplemete llame el permiso en esta (**Intro Slider**).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //LINEA PARA VERIFICAR PERMISOS
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

    } else
        finish();}
```

Igual si alguien sabe donde o como podria llamar el metodo en el MainActivity (No en el metodo Oncreate, por que volveriamos al mismo error) seria genial que lo comentara, ya que se me hace muy borde que el permiso se pida sin antes ver que existe un mapa.

Saludos, espero le sirva a alguien. Pareciera que no, pero me tomo mis buenas horas darme cuenta de esto.